# native script with angular not supporting ng-template for android

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Want to show a List View With Custom Row item in Native Script in a new page and using Xto inflate List View. But ng-template for List Item is not detected by the native script on my App.

```
<ListView  id="listView" class="list_group" item="datas" itemTap= "onItemTap($event)">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
        <StackLayout class="list-group-item">
        <Label text="item.name"></Label>
        </StackLayout>>
        </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

com.tns.nativescript/Exception

> Error is  ui/ng-template not found for element NgTemplate

Comment: `ng-template` is the way to go (not `template`) - there is a syntax error in your `items` binding (missing square brackets). You can use these examples as reference https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ui-category/listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the format for using template in listView for NativeScript Angular.

```
<ListView [items]="myItems" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
    <template let-item="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
        <StackLayout [class.odd]="odd" [class.even]="even">
            <Label [text]='"index: " + i'></Label>
            <Label [text]='"[" + item.id +"] " + item.name'></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </template>
</ListView>
```

So, try template, instead of ng-template

Source:  https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html

Comment: No... Again Error shows as "ui/template not found for Element Template". created my project through command "tns create My_Project_Name". Does it has to do anything with this?

Comment: Set up the project with
"tns create HelloWorld --template nativescript-template-ng-tutorial"
and continue from there. Or you can also install NativeScript Side Kick (which is awesome), https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-sidekick

"tns create project" sets up a nativescript core type of project.